# Software to manage Caps- and Num- lock keys

Tags: windows, keyboard

I'm looking for a free windows software which can toggle Numlock and Capslock to predefined states upon switching active window (based on keywords from window's name).

So far I found exactly one program capable of doing exactly what I want - CapsWiz. Problem is, it has month of trial and then requires paid license. Even if I wanted to pay for that, its website is dead.

Context: I'm using several programs at once and each one requires different combination of lock keys to be used efficiently. Manually changing all of that each time I change window is tedious, so I wanted to automate it.

Comment: Really? Do you mind giving a list of these programs. Sometimes  its best the real question rather than deciding on a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I use [TrayStatus](https://www.traystatus.com/) which allows you to see the Caps-lock and Num-lock status on the task bar, but they also support "triggers" to change their state with the pro version.

[image]

The pro version is not free, however there is a free 30-day trial and it's only a one-time payment of 14$ for the personal lifetime license (1 computer). It also includes update for all future versions without any recurring subscription non-sense.

And at least, the payment website works unlike CapsWiz, so at least there's that.